# Shop by filters

Tags: magento-1.9, filtered-nav

I am running a responsive theme design on Magento 1.9 with the default package going to rwd theme, and when I search a product on my mobile device, the filter results/shop by (price, category) section shows up below the product results, does anyone know how to move it to the top of the page so it shows first when the list page is loaded on mobile devices?

This screenshot is from a desktop, the filter results on mobile shows below the product listings, I would like to move it to the top of the page.

[image]

Comment: Hi JJ and welcome to MageOverflow! Please add a screenshot to make the question understandable :-)

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: can you post a screenshot for the mobile version?

Answer (score 2):

The order in which the elements appear on smaller devices is dictated by the order in which the HTML tags are placed in the template.

Looking into the the 2columns-left.phtml template, we can see that the main content block is generated before the left column.

```
<div class="main">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
    <div class="col-main">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-left sidebar">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

That means that the main content column will always be rendered before the left column, but on desktop screens, the left column has a `float: left` CSS rule while the main column has a `float: right` rule, giving the impression that the left column is rendered before the main one.

The solution is quite simple. You create a new 2columns-left.phtml template and switch the order in which the columns are rendered.

```
<div class="main">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
    <div class="col-left sidebar">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-main">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

For Magento 2 users that land up on this page, beware that this solution doesn't work. If you switch the order the filters collection will be empty. This happens because it first needs to load the product collection before generating the filters list